# Create String from all the lines in a file and store in variable

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file

I am currently having a problem. This one seemed to be pretty well covered but all the answers I found have not been working for me. What I want to do is this. I have a text file with multiple lines. I want to concat all of those to a string like

```
[LINE1]\n[LINE2]\n[LINE3]...
```

Now the answer for looping through the lines of a file I found were pretty understandable

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in (filename.key) do set content=%content% %%i
```

Now the problem is, that my batch file does loop through the file but `%content%` seems to be empty in every loop. So after all is done content just matches the last line of my file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Batch simply doesn't support multi line strings. You can concatenate to a singe line string (even with embedded CRs but no LFs).

Comment: @LotPings that's exaclty what i am trying to do ;)

Comment: The `\n` in your sample line is misleading then, it has no special meaning - just text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify your code to add [delayed](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) [expansion](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php) to it:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%A in (filename.key) do set "content=!content! %%A"
rem Your other code here....:
```

But I would do it:

```bat
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set "content="

for /F "delims=" %%A in (./config/git/read.key) do (
    if defined content (
        set "content=!content!\n%%A"
    ) else (
        set "content=%%A"
    )
)

echo %content%

rem Your other code here....:
```

You may select the way you want.

Comment: You should probably explain the limitation of how long a line can be in a batch file. Once the `SET` command hits 8192 bytes it will truncate the data.

Comment: Thanks. That almost works. The only thing is it devices the content by commas and even with the else statement i also get that delimiter at the beginning of the string.
[edit] oh and I'm getting the last line twice[/edit]

Comment: ok i must have had a typo.
for /f "delims=\n" %%i in (./config/git/read.key) do if defined content (set "content=!content!\n%%i") else (set content=%%i)
works. will edit it in the answer and accept

Comment: FOR variables are case sensitive.  You can't use an upper and lower case letter to reference the same token.